# Apache Test page showed up out from nowhere

Tags: linux, apache, centos

I've been working on a web page for a while on Centos 6.3 server
Everything was fine, the page was accessible etc.
I was screwing around trying to get pchart working, i didnt do much with it except for adding a new folder in my /var/www/html; I also tried installing GD, dont think it worked.
Now everytime I go to my web-page url i get the apache test page.

It is now giving me You dont have permissions to access / on this server

Help please

Answer (score 0):

/var/www directory is owned by the user "apache" and the group "apache", my case that had changed for some reason